# The getter 'documents' isn't defined for the type 'QuerySnapshot<Object>'

Tags: flutter

How to solve this error. I change docs.document but still error. Someone can help me?

[image]

Comment: please add querySnapshot's data (i mean i want to see what is actually in querySnapshot).

Comment: Done edit. Please check my Post

Answer (score 2):

```
FirebaseFirestore.instance
    .collection('users')
    .get()
    .then((QuerySnapshot querySnapshot) {
        querySnapshot.docs.forEach((doc) {
            print(doc["first_name"]);
        });
    });
```

A QuerySnapshot contains zero or more DocumentSnapshot objects representing the results of a query. The documents can be accessed as an array via the docs property or enumerated using the forEach method. The number of documents can be determined via the empty and size properties.

Use docs property to fetch all the documents.
In your case change documents to docs

Comment: Can you share an example with me?

Comment: querySnapshot.docs.forEach((f){
print(f.data());
})

Comment: querySnapshot.docs.forEach((f) {
            if (f.data['callStatus'] == '0') { // error
              //_alertSound();
              if (f.data['medicalPratitionerIsCalling'] == null) { //error
                if (!f.data['callerName'] //error

Comment: Please check //error after i change querySnapshot.docs.forEach((f){ print(f.data()); })

Comment: to access map data,
f.data()['callStatus']=='0'

Comment: Or to access a single field of object, you can write like f.get('callStatus')

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/243174/discussion-between-abhishek-thakur-and-john-reaper).

Comment: If the field is not available in that object than it will throw error to avoid that you can check whether that field is there or not by using f.data().containsKey("callStatus")